# SQL query that choose all values when no input

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, windows-7-x64

I've write this query in an access 2007 database:

```
SELECT Ordini.ID, Ordini.Data, Clienti.Cognome, Clienti.Nome, 
       DettagliOrdine.IDProdotto,
       Prodotti.Descrizione, Prodotti.Prezzo, DettagliOrdine.Quantità, 
       ([Prezzo]*[Quantità]) AS Totale, Ordini.Note, Produttori.Nome, Ordini.Ordinato, 
       Ordini.Arrivato, Ordini.Ritirato
FROM Produttori 
    INNER JOIN (Prodotti 
        INNER JOIN ((Clienti INNER JOIN Ordini ON Clienti.ID = Ordini.IDCliente) 
        INNER JOIN DettagliOrdine ON Ordini.ID = DettagliOrdine.IDOrdine) 
           ON Prodotti.ID = DettagliOrdine.IDProdotto) 
    ON Produttori.ID = Prodotti.IDFornitore
WHERE (((Clienti.Cognome)=[Cognome: ]) 
    AND ((Clienti.Nome)=[Nome: ]) 
    AND (([Cognome: ]) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY Ordini.Data;
```

This query brings up an input box for the COGNOME and NOME field of research.

I need that if user write nothing (press ENTER) for that field research tag is *.* (all value of that field).

es. If user write a COGNOME but not a NOME (press ENTER when popup NOME window) research to be done on all the NOME with that "COGNOME".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you want something like this ...

```sql
WHERE
    (
        Clienti.Cognome=[Cognome: ]
        OR [Cognome: ] Is Null
    )
    AND
    (
        Clienti.Nome=[Nome: ]
        OR [Nome: ] Is Null
    )
```

When the parameter value is Null, no filtering is performed based on the corresponding field.  But when the parameter value is not Null, it will be used to filter the result set so that it includes only rows with matching values.

Comment: Replace the `WHERE` clause in your query with the version I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

For a query that is executed from with Access itself you can use the `Nz()` function along with the `LIKE` operator. For example, the query

```sql
PARAMETERS [LastName: ] TEXT(255);
SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName 
FROM Clients 
WHERE LastName LIKE Nz([LastName: ],"*")
```

will return all records<sup>*</sup> if enter nothing at the `LastName:` prompt, but will return only the records with the specified [LastName] if I type something in at the prompt.

<sup>*</sup>Actually, all records *for which a LastName exists* (i.e., IS NOT NULL). Thanks to HansUp for the correction.

Comment: `WHERE LastName LIKE "*"` excludes rows with Null for `LastName` ... which may be what Domenico actually wants, but I thought he meant *all* rows.

Comment: I'm sorry but don't works..don't select correct request if I write something in popup window, select always all...how can I do?

Comment: @Domenico The simple example in my answer works for me. If you edit your question with the actual query you are trying to use maybe somebody can identify why your query doesn't behave the same way.